# How to get Client id and client secret when we registered in instagram..?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I am beginner of iPhone developer. I want to get client id. I have already registered in instagram but in my mail id I can not get client id. so, Please give you any document and suggestion which is apply in my instagram account.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to get client id and client secret in instagarm:

```
1. After login click on manage client.
2.Then click on register a new client.
3.Complete the process and after that yu will get your id and secret.
```